# Scheme List Derangement (Rearrangement of sorts)

Tags: list, function, functional-programming, scheme

im trying to write a function in Scheme where i accept a list and return all the different **derangements** (look below for definition) as a list of lists

**derangement**: A list where no item is in the same place as the original list
ex: '(a b c) -> '(cab)

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Compute all of the permutations of the input list and then filter out the ones that have an element in the same position as the input list. If you need more detail, leave a comment.

#### Edit 1:

Define (or maybe it's defined already? Good exercise, anyway) a procedure called `filter` that takes as its first argument a procedure `p` and a list `l` as its second argument. Return a list containing only the values for which `(p l)` returns a truthy value.

Define a procedure `derangement?` that tests if a list `l1` is a derangement of `l2`. This will be handy when paired with `filter`.

Comment: its not homework, but then i really don't have any proof :( it's actually practice for scheme, just doing all the different things that i can do with lists...we had to do different operations in C, so using the same template to practice scheme. I've got permutations working, i just dont know how to filter it. I figure i have to look at the position of each element (maybe element-at-index?, ive got working code for that as well)....but i cant figure out how to recursively check.

Comment: @Princeton2231: I'll take your word for it. Try recursing through the input list. If it's an element you want to keep, make a `cons` cell with the element you want to keep as `car` and the result of recursing through the rest of the list as the `cdr`. If you don't want to keep the element, just don't make the new `cons`.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be something like this:

```
    (define filtered-permutations
      (lambda (lst)
        (filter
         (lambda (permuted-list)
           (deranged? permuted-list lst))
         (permute lst))))
```

Since the number of derangements is considerably lower than then number of permutations, however, this is not very efficient. Here is a solution that mostly avoids generating permutations that are not derangements, but does use `filter` once, for the sake of simplicity:

```
(define deranged?
  (lambda (lst1 lst2)
    (if (null? lst1)
        #t
        (if (eq? (car lst1) (car lst2))
            #f
            (deranged? (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))))

(define derange
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (< (length lst) 2)
        ;; a list of zero or one elements can not be deranged
        '()
        (permute-helper lst lst))))

(define derange-helper
  (lambda (lst template)
      (if (= 2 (length lst))
          (let ((one (car lst))
                (two (cadr lst)))
            (filter
             (lambda (x)
               (deranged? x template))
             (list (list one two) (list two one))))
          (let ((anchor (car template)))
            (let loop ((todo lst)
                       (done '())
                       (result '()))
              (if (null? todo)
                  result
                  (let ((item (car todo)))
                    (if (eq? item anchor)
                        ;; this permutation would not be a derangement
                        (loop (cdr todo)
                              (cons item done)
                              result)
                        (let ((permutations
                               (map
                                (lambda (x)
                                  (cons item x))
                                (derange-helper (append (cdr todo) done)
                                                (cdr template)))))
                          (loop (cdr todo)
                                (cons item done)
                                (append result permutations)))))))))))
```